# How do I fix this file?

Tags: javascript

I am making a game for a school project, and I have added a simple animation that was a lot of work. The animation is of an arrow following the curve of a parabola. To do this, I had to make the arrow rotate to follow the arrow. This works perfectly on a file on my computer, but when I open it on my website it rotates the whole canvas and gets messed up. How do I fix this? This is the file on my computer: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ugbwnwgghegm1ot/Animation.html?dl=0 .Then click open, to open the file on your computer.  The website is here: http://www.riddles.gq/Archer.html , then go to Archer.

Thank You

Comment: how about some code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Chrome is throwing a lot of InvalidState errors in F12. Maybe it's related to that. You need to extract the problematic code & post in in your question to get a good answer in StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is because your image src is invalid, just replace

`<img id="scream" width="2" height="2" src="Arrow2.jpg" alt="arrow">`

by

`<img id="scream" width="2" height="2" src="" alt="arrow">`

now it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried what you said and it worked perfectly!!

Comment: You're welcome, you can now mark this question as answered.